# Is there a way to fix auto indentation in netbeans, netbeans curly braces auto insert does something weird?

Tags: netbeans, insert, auto, braces

After pressing curly braces at the end of loop NetBeans auto indentation does this with **inner for loops**, in other cases works fine

```cpp
for (size_t j{}; j < size2; j++){

                                }
```

Ending brace `}` doesn't align with keyword `for` but it does with opening brace

I expect following indentation

```cpp
for (size_t j{}; j < size2; j++){

}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Especially it does with inner for loop. In other cases it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stackoverflow question asked 8 years ago that is very similar to this one.

In conclusion it's a bug and you might reformat the code by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7614364/6884722

Comment: It would be productive if it automatically indents. Yes, Alt+Shift+F is shortcut to indent but if there is a way around to deal with this bug would be better. Thanks for your reply Ricardo J. Chamorro.